# How to update a form field as you type in value into another field

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

Good Day, 
I'm trying to create a form calculate (a currency converter), in which when you are typing in the value of amount in USD, the other field is updated immediately without clicking any submit button. I have been searching but haven't gotten an answer (maybe due to searching for the wrong keywords).

An Example

```
<html>
    <form action="">
        <input type="number" name="amountUSD" value="1"><br/>
        <input type="number" name="amountNGN" value="">
    </form>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve is when the page loads, automatically, the value of amountNGN field should be 365 and of I remove the value of amountUSD field or make the value 0, the 365 in amountNGN field should go away or become 0.

Which makes the calculation: value(amountNGN) = value(amountUSD) * 356; (just an illustration,  not sure this language exist).

The value of amountNGN field updates on the fly. Please how can I use JavaScript/jQuery to do this

Thanks

Comment: <input type="number" name="amountUSD" value="1" onchange="abracaDabra()">

Comment: Please put some effort in your task and come back with more code so we can help you. At the moment you ask to code the whole assignment for you. You have the idea of what you want to achieve, you mentioned the programming languages to use so give it a try yourself.

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak ... Thanks for the reply but I'm not sure how to go about the abracaDabra() function, is it something you can help with a snippet to achieve my question?. Thanks once again

Comment: @pr1nc3 Honestly, I don't know how to move up from here. I know how to POST a form and calculation whatever I want using PHP but I need the amountNGN field to automatically update the value of amountUSD * 365, then the value in amountNGN field is what will be posted during submission. That's why I stated that I want the amountNGN field to updated without any click of a button as clicking the button of the form will do another task which is out of the scope of the question

Comment: @KolawoleEmmanuelIzzy it is a joke. Indeed you should do some work before posting

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak I have done some work, the form is more than this but this is the part of the form that I need to figure out before the full form can work... I actually want to create a form to create a product in woocommerce from front-end and after all my research and code to put together are ready, I need a converter to convert USD amount to NGN in which the NGN is what will be posted to woocommerce. That's why I limit the question to the aspect I have issue with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```js
function convertCurrency(value) {
    // your calculation here
    return (value * 356);
}

$('[name="amountUSD"]').on('change keyup', function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    $('[name="amountNGN"]').val(convertCurrency(value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="number" name="amountUSD" value="1"><br/>
    <input type="number" name="amountNGN" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt, Thanks for your response. Your Snippet works but i have to click outside before it update the second field. I would like the second field to update along with the first field, as i am typing in amount into the first field, the second field should return the value alongside. Is this possible as that is my question?

Comment: Yes, some browsers handle the `change` event differently, I've added a `keyup` event as well like suggested in Mbotet's answer which I hope is what you're looking for.

Comment: You're the best. Thanks so much, works perfectly. Lastly on this line return `(value * 356);` can i add a php code to this (i.e pulling the exchange rate from a set value somewhere else using php). e.g `(value * <?php echo $currencyExchange; ?>);` .. Is it possible?

Comment: You can do this if your JavaScript is in your php file using `<script>` tags. Otherwise, you could retrieve the value from a hidden input field using something like this: `var exchangeRate = $('#hiddenInput').val()` and in php: `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $currencyExchange; ?>" id="hiddenInput" />`

Comment: Alright thanks.. I Noticed something with the above code. After i added the code and the increment was working as expecting, i noticed that the value of the second field remains 0 and if i'm to POST the form it doesn't recognize the updated value.

Comment: Please ignore my above comment question. Everything works perfectly fine now.. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want your server to do this work then use ajax (not recommended, but posible).

If you want to change it on client side JAVASCRIPT will do the job (but then is not a php question); I recommend using the onkeyup javascript event on the field you are working with referencing the one you want to change.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes, I am okay with the JavaScript code since that is more recommended ... I just want that field to automatically update value which is what I will POST using php to complete the application

Comment: I would even add an extra validation on the update button (event) to make sure the data is formatted the way you wanted. If i helped you in any way please vote up :D

Comment: Sure I will, will be expecting the code. @matt already gave me an answer which is what I'm working with currently but I don't mind having another approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as I cannot reply in a commment (not enough reputation currently), I try it this way.

For me, the answer given earlier works perfectly, but I have an extra question.

To change the value, the name of the field (name = "amountNGN") is hardcoded. Is there a way to make this dynamic?

I have a container containing all fields name for which I want to get the value from, so I want to loop this container and get the values, but I don't seem to get it working

```js
function convertCurrency(value) {
    // your calculation here
    return (value * 356);
}

$('[name="amountUSD"]').on('change keyup', function() {
    value = $(this).val();
    $('[name="amountNGN"]').val(convertCurrency(value));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="number" name="amountUSD" value="1"><br/>
    <input type="number" name="amountNGN" value="">
</form>
```